# Collecting user information

Tags: paypal

I need to collect information about our high school reunion attendees and allow them to pay via a PayPal button. I've created the PayPal Pay Now button, but not sure what if any information will be collected and sent back to me. Do I need a separate form to collect information or is there a way to make the PayPal button work as the submit button for the data I collect using a form?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for this. There are lots of good templates for this available on GitHub. Your form might look like this:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOUR PAYPAL ID">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM_NAME">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="ITEM_NUMBER>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="TOTAL_AMOUNT">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $attendee_id ?>">

    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to website">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://domain.com/success.php"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://domain.com/ipn.php"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://domain.com/canceled.php"/>
    <button type="submit">Pay using PayPal</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not using the PayPal api. I'm only using the button you create on the PayPal website and paste the code into your website. PayPal isn't clear about what information will be captured and sent back to me so I will know who has registered and their contact info. So far it looks like I have to do registration in two steps: 1. Get users to submit their data in one form and then pay using the PayPal button I put on the success page of the form submission. I'm trying to do both in one step.

Comment: You don't have to use the API. The form above is the standard form with some extra fields to work with the IPN. You should use a IPN to get responses from PayPal. The IPN does just that what you're looking for.